# Pop Up Modal Asp.Net redirect

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having the following problem. I present a data edit page, but I am unable to return to the homepage without refreshing the page. Because there is data in this index page that I can not update to lose, because they come from another view. Edit page needs to return to search result

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? IDUsuarioT)
    {
        if (Session["EstaLogado"] != null && Session["TokenUsuario"] != null)
        {
            var dados = "";
            string token = Session["TokenUsuario"].ToString();
            string IdUsuario = Session["IdUsuario"].ToString();

            IRestResponse response = helper.RequisicaoRest(urlUsuario + "/", dados, token, "GET");

            if (response.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
            {
                ViewBag.usuarios = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Usuario>(response.Content);
                //return PartialView();
               return PartialView("Edit");
            }

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
    }



    //encaminhar a solicitacao de demanda da pesquisa
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OfferCreate(FormCollection sCreate)
    {
        if (Session["EstaLogado"] != null && Session["TokenUsuario"] != null)
        {
            var dados = "";
            string token = Session["TokenUsuario"].ToString();
            string IDUsuarioOrig = Session["IDUsuario"].ToString();
            dados += "&IDUsuarioOrig=" + IDUsuarioOrig;
            dados += "&Titulo=" + sCreate["Titulo"].ToString();
            dados += "&Descricao=" + sCreate["Descricao"].ToString();
            dados += "&Nome=" + sCreate["Nome"].ToString();
            dados += "&Telefone=" + sCreate["Telefone"].ToString();
            dados += "&Email=" + sCreate["Email"].ToString();
            dados += "&IDUsuarioDest=" + sCreate["IDUsuarioT"].ToString();
            string DataRetorno = DateTime.Now.AddDays(+20).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            dados += "&DataRetorno=" + DataRetorno;
            IRestResponse response = helper.RequisicaoRest(urldemandaCreate, dados, token, "POST");
            if (response.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
            {
                TempData["Success-demanda"] = "Demanda encaminhada ao responsável  =) ";
                return PartialView("Edit");
            }
            return View();
        }
        return View();

    }
    //retorno mudanca das info
    public ActionResult ResultadoBusca(FormCollection busca)
    {
        if (Session["EstaLogado"] != null && Session["TokenUsuario"] != null)
        {

            var dados = "";
            string token = Session["TokenUsuario"].ToString();
            string IdUsuario = Session["IdUsuario"].ToString();
            string cidade = busca["cidade"].ToString();
            string uf = busca["uf"].ToString();
            string profissional = busca["profissional"].ToString();
            dados += "/" + cidade;
            dados += "/" + uf;
            dados += "/" + profissional;

            IRestResponse response = helper.RequisicaoRest(urlpesquisa + dados, token, "GET");
            if (response.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
            {
                ViewBag.searchadados = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Usuario>>(response.Content);
                return View();
            }
            TempData["SuccessET"] = "Não foi encontrado nenhum profissional habilitado para sua solicitação !";
            return View("index");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely have to use JavaScript to do that, I'm guessing.
Are you using a save button in your "Edit" partial view?  If so, then last action of the save function should be a page redirect.

I'm thinking you're probably using AJAX to save the Edited data?  If so, then it should be a simple call of:  **document.location.href='{*new page you want to go to*}**

Comment: <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit"class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>&nbsp;
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>

Comment: In my edit page I have the fields and after filled I forward to the OfferCreate controller

Comment: But in redirection it ends up losing the information it had previously in the view and I don't want to refresh this page

Comment: have you tried using TempData?  You could also store that data in Session temporarily.  If it isn't a huge amount of data, Session and/or TempData should suffice.  You could also use LocalStorage.

Comment: Problem was circumvented from partview